# SharePoint 2019 document library takes 30 seconds to update metadata column

Tags: performance, csom, sharepointdocumentlibrary, sharepoint-2019

I have a document library in SharePoint 2019 with document sets and folders. At this moment it has more than 52K+ documents. I am using CSOM to create and update the document sets.
Create new report set - 6-8 seconds
Update any metadata column - 30 to 35 seconds.

Library is consumed by Provider hosted add-in deployed on-prem.

Update takes lot of time and sometimes time out.

What could be possible reason for this?

I have put optimal amount of Indexes on the library. Only major versions are enabled on library.

- Optimal number of Indexes have been added to the library
- CSOM queries are optimised properly

Looking into Sql fragmentation issues